# Requirejs combined application window.onerror error handling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, error-handling, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

In a Backbone and requirejs 2x based application, **only when the application is combined** through grunt-contrib-require, window.onerror stops trapping errors.

The window.onerror function id declared before and outside the Backbone application and send errors to a backend.

Sorry, cannot post much of the application but those interested parts

this is my app/main.js file

```javascript
require(["config"], function () {

    // config is a require.config({}); definition

    require(["app", "router"], function (app, Router) {
        app.initialize(new Router());
    });

});
```

Gruntfile.js section regarding requirejs task

```javascript
    requirejs : {
        debug : {
            options : {
                mainConfigFile : "app/config.js",
                generateSourceMaps : false,
                include : [ "main" ],
                insertRequire : [ "main" ],
                out : "app.combined.js",
                optimize : "none",
                findNestedDependencies : true,
                name : "config",
                baseUrl : "app",
                wrap : false,
                preserveLicenseComments : false
            }
        }
    }
```

Embed of the not combined application:

```html
<script>
  window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, colno, error) {
     console.debug('onerror',arguments);
     // data will be sent to backend

     // TRACE FIRED

  }
</script>

<script src="require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>
```

Embed of the combined application:

```html
<script>
  window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, colno, error) {
     console.debug('onerror',arguments);
     // data will be sent to backend

     // TRACE NOT FIRED
  }
</script>
<script src="app.combined.js" ></script>
```

any suggestion welcome! thank you.

Comment: Can you link to the contents of the combined JS?

Comment: What sets `window.onerror`. How is it loaded when the application is a set of modules? How is it loaded when the application is combined? How do you "combine" your application (show the exact method)? Add the answers to all of this to your question.

Comment: I don't see how `app.combined.js` can load properly. There is no indication that RequireJS is included in the bundle and you do not load RequireJS with a `script` element.

Comment: Thank you Luis for the interest, but i found a solution

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution to this.

I should **declare the window.onerror after window load**.

```js
    $(window).load(function() {

      window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, colno, error) {

        console.debug('onerror',arguments);

        // data will be sent to backend

        // TRACE FIRED
     };
    });

    <script src="app.combined.js" ></script>
```